# phpunit testing not installed

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit

I am trying to install PHPUNIT however i get phpunit not install message

I am using ubuntu environment. I have also installed xampp. I downloaded phpunit at phpunit website and i follow the instruction given

wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar

➜ chmod +x phpunit.phar

➜ mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit  my path is /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit

➜ phpunit --version

when i try to type phpunit --version. i was asked to installed phpunit. instead of the version description.

Hope someone out there could help me out

Comment: try /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit --version

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can use:
sudo apt-get install phpunit

Answer (score 0):

phpunit's installation will be easier if you install it through composer, you will have an executable located in vendor/bin.
According you have a composer installed (or https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev

Using phpunit like this will avoid some issues about version of the binary used for running tests.